What could have the missing word been here? (a crass rhyme cited in Orwell's Down and Out in Paris and London)
In his Down and Out in Paris and London, Orwell mentions the following rhyme:

He that takes away the sugar
Shall be called a dirty -----

being written on a wall of a coffee-shop. But the last word is scraped off. ("This is England", Orwell jokes.)
My question is: What is the missing word? I'm not a native speaker, so not an expert on 1930s slang and swearwords.

I don't know what the writer was thinking of, but I can identify four potential words to fill the gap.

Said in a (British) northern accent, 'sugar' rhymes with 'bugger'.

@WeatherVane That was certainly one of my alternatives :-)

@Stanislav if the word was scratched out, how do you know the rhyme is crass? The book's text only says "some poetic customer had written..." Is the question a set-up?

@WeatherVane I understood "This is England." to mean "The British, exactly as the stereotype says, care about politeness so much they will scratch off a dirty word from a grafitti". I mean, why would someone scratch off the final word of a line if it were not offensive in any way?

An offensive rhyme need not be crass. It can be apposite or poetic, as the text says.

"Bugger"
OED: Bugger (n.)

3.b.slang and colloquial. Used familiarly or playfully to express affection, compassion, etc.: a person or (occasionally) an animal.
Chiefly with modifying adjective as little, lazy, poor, silly, etc.
Cf. beggar n. 6b, beggar n.
1982 Just so I don't get labelled as a cranky old bugger who does
nothing but complain. Overlander September 5
2014 The young of today are just a bunch of lazy buggers who've never
had it so good. Sydney Morning Herald (Nexis) 31 May 38

The term is now considered only mildly offensive and comparable to "damn".

Would you say the meaning started as fooker and now, more like jerk?

Interesting. There are similarities but "bugger" started life as "sodomizer/heretic". It then passed into a term of denigration for Bulgars but then (19th c.) became confused with "beggar". This, the forgotten history and a lack of opportunity to use the noun seems to have taken the wind out of its sails and hence the lessening of the force. Fooker had a very short life, (OED - 2 entries a year apart and one in a foreign accent as a double-entendre). So "fucker" was not softened by a common close homonym although it has lost force in a restricted context and overexposure.

Your OED examples, interestingly, date from 1982. Orwell's work was published in 1933, Orwell was born in 1903. I very much doubt the derogatory sense of "bugger" had significantly changed in the late 1920s

EDITED The reason that bugger was scratched out  wasn't because its meaning was affectionate, similar to bloke or geezer  but because in the early 20th century until the 1960s (this is my guess) it was an offensive term for a man who was a homosexual. The verb sense "buggering something up“ implied that something fucked up badly.
